# How to create a SelectItem instance in JSF, which cannot be selected on gui (but which is always visible as default in a selectOneMenu)?

Tags: java, jsf

For example i have this jsf component:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.field}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{bean.myFieldSelection}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

How can i create a kind of SelectItem, which is visble in gui as default, if the xhtmal page will be loaded, but which cannot be selected by the user? How can i create this SelectItem instance with java?

Comment: have you tried<f:selectItem itemLabel="---" noSelectionOption="true" /> it should be placed before your <f:selectItems value="#{bean.myFieldSelection}" />

Comment: i use JSF 1.2, so that option doesn´t work